# "Unauthorized" when using read.csv on a https link in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I have a link which leads to a .csv file if I directly click on it, but when I try to read it in R, the output just shows unauthorized.

Please see codes below, I both want to read a .csv file from a link, the first one works perfectly, but in the second one, the output just shows "unauthorized; Invalid cookie etc." although it's a public link.

```r
library(readr)
library(RCurl)
download <- getURL("https://data.kingcounty.gov/api/views/yaai-7frk/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD")
data <- read.csv (text = download)
# Below doesn't work
download <- getURL("https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/^IXIC?period1=1556161210&period2=1558753210&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=dQjP5bTJfZn")
data <- read.csv (text = download)
```

I wonder what is causing the issue? Does the website has some protection against non-browser access or do I need to add something in my code?

Comment: Well, I can't access the URL from by browser so it's not exactly "public". Perhaps it's a site that requires a login. When you use `getURL` you won't have any off the cookies that may have been set in your browser.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks, I didn't realize it actually record the browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A technique that works with one form of web scraping in R may not work with other types of websites. Accessing data from financial websites is a case in point. Here is where knowing the best R package(s) for a particular problem is invaluable.

One can use the `quantmod` package to access data from Yahoo Finance. Using the stock ticker from the OP, here is an example of how to use `quantmod` to access the 2018 data for the Nasdaq Composite Stock Index.

```
library(quantmod)
from.dat <- as.Date("01/01/18",format="%m/%d/%y")
to.dat <- as.Date("12/31/18",format="%m/%d/%y")
# access 2018 data for the Nasdaq Composite Index 
getSymbols("^IXIC",from=from.dat,to=to.dat,src="yahoo")
head(IXIC)
```

...and the results:

```
> head(IXIC)
           IXIC.Open IXIC.High IXIC.Low IXIC.Close IXIC.Volume IXIC.Adjusted
2018-01-02   6937.65   7006.91  6924.08    7006.90  1914930000       7006.90
2018-01-03   7017.07   7069.15  7016.70    7065.53  2166780000       7065.53
2018-01-04   7089.50   7098.05  7072.38    7077.91  2098890000       7077.91
2018-01-05   7105.74   7137.04  7097.08    7136.56  2020900000       7136.56
2018-01-08   7135.38   7161.35  7124.09    7157.39  2051430000       7157.39
2018-01-09   7174.19   7181.14  7148.30    7163.58  2107300000       7163.58
>
```

Note that `quantmod` does not require authentication credentials or cookies to access data from Yahoo Finance.

### Obtaining a list of stock symbols

Responding to a comment on my answer, here is code that will allow one to process a list of stock tickers in an `apply()` function.

```
tickers <- c("^IXIC","GOOG","IBM")
# get a list of symbols
tickerList <- lapply(tickers,function(x){
     message(paste("getting symbol:",x))
     aName <- getSymbols(x,from=from.dat,to=to.dat,src="yahoo")
     assign(aName,get(aName),envir = .GlobalEnv) # assign to global env
     aName
})
```

Once `lapply()` finishes, one can observe the `xts` data structures in the RStudio environment viewer, as illustrated in the following screen capture.

[image]

Comment: Within a loop, `getSymbols()` saves the data to a closure that is released when the loop completes. I'll update my answer with code that writes the data to the Global Environment so it can be accessed once the loop ends. I'll use an `apply()` function rather than a loop, however.